# How to make a binary expression tree from a postfix expression?

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, tree, stack

I have been trying to write this code for a while now and even though I know what to do, I am still unable to figure out my error.

The goal was to take a postfix expression and convert it to binary expression tree and then traverse it.

My logic was:

1. If it wasn't an operator, I made a leaf node 'temp' ( i.e `temp->Left=temp->Right=NULL`) and pushed it onto an array based stack of type tree.
2. If it was an operator, I inserted it onto a tree 'T' and then popped my stack twice to add `T->Left` and `T->Right`.
3. I then pushed the resultant 'T' onto stack and loop iterated till the expression was read.

My loop iterated fine and even my stack has one entry remaining at the end but I can't call InOrder, PostOrder or PreOrder traversal onto the resultant as it keeps crashing my program.

My main code is:

```
while(expression[i]!='\0'){
    if(expression[i]==' '){
        i++;
        continue;
    }
    if(expression[i]!='*' &&
       expression[i]!='/' &&
       expression[i]!='-' &&
       expression[i]!='+'){

        temp = MakeEmpty(NULL);
        temp=Insert(expression[i],temp);
        Push(temp,S);
    }else{
        T=Insert(expression[i],T);
        Operand2=TopAndPop(S);
        Operand1=TopAndPop(S);
        T=FullTree(Operand1,Operand2,T);
        Push(T,S);
        T=MakeEmpty(NULL);   //It just needed to be reset
    }
    i++;
}
```

Additional codes can be provided.

FullTree function just sets Operand1 as `T->Left` and `Operand2` as `T->Right`.
InOrder traversal traverses left, prints the `T->Element` and then traverses right.

I really appreciate any help that I can get.Also, if I made any mistakes in posting, kindly guide me so I won't do it again.

Comment: Try running your program from inside a debugger. Make sure you compile your program with debugging information enabled if you are using a command shell to invoke your compiler.

Comment: It would be much easier to do this recursively. Have a single function that returns a tree node. If it pops a value off the stack, then return that value as a leaf node. If it pops an operator that operates on two values, have it create a tree node, and call itself for both child nodes. That's it. (For useful error messages, use a structure with a pointer to the "bad" stack element, initialized to "no error". Pass a pointer to that structure to the recursive function, and have it bail out if the error structure indicates an error already occurred.)

Comment: "Keeps crashing my program" isn't much to go on. Is there an error message displayed when the program crashes? Does it tell you on what line it crashes? Have you run the program in a debugger? We can't help if you don't give us more information.

Comment: It works now.I just needed to make my tree empty before exiting the while loop in else case.
It changed the structure of tree and therefore traversal gave that crash error